# Adding classes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does [the following code](http://jsfiddle.net/zM7KU/) not work?  I am using FF 30.0.  When I click the hamburger icon made, all 3 lines should turn red.

```
function toggle() {
   document.getElementsByClassName("line").classList.add("test");
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList. Also your fiddle isn't setup properly.

Comment: @elclanrs In fact, it returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to iterate the [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) instance returned by [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName):

```
function toggle() {
    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("line");
    for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i)
        els[i].classList.add("test");
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zM7KU/1/)

Comment: Wow, thanks to this answer, finally I'm a trusted user! @Joshuasm32 You can try `toggle` instead of `add`: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zM7KU/2/).